# How to restrict special characters < and > in input value for a column

Tags: plsql

I am not that fluent in using regular expressions. I want that user should not provide value for a column with '<' or '>' in it.

Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Use group `()` and or `|` operators for example to validate user input you sould do:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  l_value varchar2(32767) := '<p>test and data</p>';
begin
  if regexp_like(l_value,'(<|>)','i') then
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid');
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('valid');  
  end if;
end;
/
```

Good luck.

Comment: wow!! thankyou very much, that was precise. I was trying what not.. thanks once again.

Comment: Hi, If I use a < or > in your valid case string, it still shows valid but it should become invalid now.

Comment: @SachinVaidya please note that valid case is commented out, in provided sample so, I had to edit answer to prevent ambiguous interpretation. Others variations will works like William Robertson said.

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate. Sorry for misinterpreting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[` and `]` to define a set of characters to match, e.g. `[abc]`, `[a-z]`, `[a-z0-9_]`

```
select string
     , case
          when regexp_like(string,'[<>]') then 'Invalid'
          else 'Valid'
       end as test
from  
       ( select '<p>text</p>' as string from dual union all
         select 'text' from dual );

STRING           TEST
---------------- -------
<p>text</p>      Invalid
text             Valid
```

Or in PL/SQL:

```
declare
    teststring varchar2(100) := '<p>test and data</p>';
    regex      varchar2(100) := '[<>]';
begin
    dbms_output.put('"'||teststring||'"');
    dbms_output.put(case when regexp_like(teststring,regex) then ' matches ' else ' does not match ' end );
    dbms_output.put(regex);
    dbms_output.new_line();
end;
/

"<p>test and data</p>" matches [<>]

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

As a check constraint:

```
create table mytable
( col varchar2(20)
      constraint mytable_ltgt_chk check ( not regexp_like(col,'[<>]') )
);
```

Test:

```
insert into mytable (col) values ('kitten > puppy');
```

rejected with:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (MYRIAD_OWNER_82.MYTABLE_LTGT_CHK) violated
```

If you wanted to exclude square brackets as well, that would be:

```
constraint mytable_symbol_chk check ( not regexp_like(col,'[][<>]') );
```

Or without any regex:

```
constraint mytable_symbol_chk check ( col = translate(col,'[]<>','.') )
```

https://regex101.com/r/oQJztM/2/tests

Comment: This is very helpful as well. What if I do not need a '[' or ']' symbol? will ^ help in this case?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether the text contains the symbols `[` or `]`? Just include them in the regex.

Comment: Hi , what I want is , I want to put a constraint on a column values to allow them everything except < or >. So I was trying something like,                              ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT "mytable_CHK" CHECK ((REGEXP_LIKE(col,^'(<|>)','i'))). Not sure it will work that way though.

Comment: Added check constraint example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate that you added the check constraint example as well.